# unity ads not showing up

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads, banner

i followed the official unity tutorial on how to put bannner ads on my game, i set everything up in the unity dashboard, and in the editor i see a rectangle that says the ad should be there, but when i build the game nothing shows up, here is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class bannerad : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool testMode = false;
    public string gameId = "******" (my game id is here i just dot want to share it);
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, testMode);

        while (!Advertisement.IsReady("Lost_Ad"))
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        Advertisement.Banner.SetPosition(BannerPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);

        Advertisement.Banner.Show("Lost_Ad"); 
    }






}
```

anyone knows what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you ever calling this function? If you just replaced the `Start` function with this `IEnumerator` it will not get called unless you call it.

```
private void Start()
{
     Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, testMode);
     StartCoroutine(StartAds());
}

private IEnumerator StartAds()
{
     // your code here 
}
```